# How can I convert * )xÿª5c’√K’Rk¬É* to plain text in objective C?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring, hex, nsdata

Please check here is my code

```
int asciiCode = @"29 78 D8 BB 35 12 63 D5 C3 4B 18 D5 52 6B C2 83";
NSString *strings = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", asciiCode];
NSLog(@"%c",strings);
}
```

if the value of **29 78 D8 BB 35 12 63 D5 C3 4B 18 D5 52 6B C2 83** it should display as **india is my** string value but it is displaying as **)xÿª5c’√K’Rk¬É**

Answer (score 5):

```
int asciiCode = @"29 78 D8 BB 35 12 63 D5 C3 4B 18 D5 52 6B C2 83";
```

This is invalid. `@"..."` is a NSString, not an int.

You could have a char array, like this:

```
char *asciiCode = {0x29, 0x78, 0xD8, 0xBB, ...}
```

Which you could turn into a NSString using

```
NSString *strings = [NSString stringWithCString:asciiCode usingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: You cannot initialize a `char *` using an array initializer.

Answer (score 2):

The characters you have shown aren't ASCII, as they have their 8th bit set, but they could be UTF-8 encoded?  If so, you simply need to treat them like a NUL-terminated C-String:

```
unsigned char cstr[] = { 0x29, 0x78, 0xD8, 0xBB, 0x35, 0x12, 0x63, 0xD5, 0xC3,
                         0x4B, 0x18, 0xD5, 0x52, 0x6B, 0xC2, 0x83, 0x0 };
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:cstr];
NSLog(@"%@",string);
```

or:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cstr];
NSLog(@"%@",string);
```

Depending on whether you want a retained or autoreleased `NSString` object.

Answer (score 0):

You could also prepend your character codes with `\x`. For example:

```
NSString *string = @"\x29 \x78 \xD8 \xBB \x35 \x12 \x63 \xD5 \xC3 \x4B \x18 \xD5 \x52 \x6B \xC2 \x83";
NSLog(@"%@",string);
```

But beware that the codes should be in hexadecimal. for example, 29 here is hexadecimal 29 (0x29) not in decimal.